# SQL additional rows with calculated values

Tags: sql-server

I have the following result set:

```
SELECT type, productid, source, product, term, milespa, maintained 
FROM pricing

type productid source  product term milespa maintained
car  75850     LENDER1 FL      2    8000    442.80
car  75850     LENDER1 FL      2    30000   532.70
```

The table only contains pricing for 8000 and 30000 mileages. I need to change the query so it calculates the price for all the 1000 mileage increments in between, so for example to calculate 9000 would be:

```
(30000 - 8000) / 1000 = 22 --the number of increments
(532.70 - 442.80) = 89.90 --difference between 8k and 30k
--9000 price = 8000 price + the difference divided into increments so 442.80 + (89.90 / 22 * 1) = 446.88         
10000 would be 442.80 + (89.90 / 22 * 2) = 450.97
```

and so on...

Can I do that so a single query will return all the calculated pricing I need?

Thanks

Comment: What if there are more than 2 records for the product_id? Do you average out based on the furthest apart? Will say diff between 1st and 3rd per 1000 give same as difference between 2nd and 3rd per 1000?

Comment: There will only ever be 2 records per (type,productid,source,product,term) combination, always an 8000 and 30000.

Comment: BTW you have a logic error in your question. Change : "so for example to calculate 9000 would be:"  to ...  so for example to calculate 10000 would be:

Answer (score 0):

I like splitting the problem in little chunks (subqueries or CTEs). You haven't included your table's definition so I can't fully test this, but it should give you a good idea of how to solve your concern.

```
;WITH MissingMileages AS -- Generate all missing mileages from 9k to 30k in 1k increments (recursive CTE)
(
    SELECT
        MissingMileage = 9000

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MissingMileage = M.MissingMileage + 1000
    FROM
        MissingMileages AS M
    WHERE
        M.MissingMileage + 1000 < 30000
),
MaintainedPriceByIncrement AS -- Determine the maintained price for 1k increment by each key columns
(
    SELECT
        P8.productid,
        P8.type,
        P8.source,
        P8.product,
        P8.term,
        maintainedByIncrement = (P30.maintained - P8.maintained) / 22
    FROM
        pricing AS P8
        INNER JOIN pricing AS P30 ON 
            P8.productId = P30.productId AND
            P8.type = P30.type AND
            P8.source = P30.source AND
            P8.product = P30.product AND
            P8.term = P30.term
    WHERE
        P8.milespa = 8000 AND
        P30.milespa = 30000
),
AllAvailableProducts AS -- List all products to expand mileage (1 row per entity)
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        P.productid,
        P.type,
        P.source,
        P.product,
        P.term,
    FROM
        pricing AS P
)
SELECT
    A.productid,
    M.MissingMileage,
    MissingMaintained = P.maintainedByIncrement * (M.MissingMileage / 1000)
FROM
    AllAvailableProducts AS A

    -- Expand all products with all missing mileages
    CROSS JOIN MissingMileages AS M

    -- ... and retrieve the increment by 1k mileage for that particular product
    INNER JOIN MaintainedPriceByIncrement AS P ON
        A.productId = P.productId AND
        A.type = P.type AND
        A.source = P.source AND
        A.product = P.product AND
        A.term = P.term

ORDER BY
    A.productid,
    M.MissingMileage
```

Answer (score 0):

**Let me know if this helps.**

You can run it [here](https://rextester.com/WCNR67514) to verify.

I've only extracted the pertinent columns out of your original table to make this work.

Adapt it to suit your needs.

```
create table #pricing (
productid int,
milespa int,
maintained smallmoney
);  
insert into #pricing VALUES(75850,8000,442.80); 
insert into #pricing VALUES(75850,30000,532.70); 
create table #mileage (
   miles smallint
);
insert into #mileage VALUES(8000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(9000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(10000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(11000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(12000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(13000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(14000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(15000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(16000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(17000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(18000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(19000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(20000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(21000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(22000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(23000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(24000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(25000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(26000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(27000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(28000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(29000);
insert into #mileage VALUES(30000);
WITH m8000 (productid, maintained8000) AS 
(
  select productid, maintained  
  FROM #pricing 
  WHERE productid = 75850
  AND   milespa =8000
),
m30000 (productid, maintained30000) AS
(
  select productid,maintained  
  FROM #pricing 
  WHERE productid = 75850
  AND   milespa =30000
),
maint (productid, per1000, starting) AS
(
select  m8.productid, ((m30.maintained30000 - m8.maintained8000) /22) AS per1000, m8.maintained8000
FROM m8000 m8
JOIN m30000 m30
ON m8.productid = m30.productid
)
select mt.productid, mi.miles, replace(cast((((mi.miles - 8000)/1000) * mt.per1000 + mt.starting) as numeric(10,2)),',','.')AS maintained
from maint mt
cross join #mileage mi
```

---

- Note the REPLACE part may not be necessary for you.
- It may be a REXTESTER thing. I just didn't want commas where decimal point should go.